# Does PHP "serialize" think "html" must be a suffix? Why does it remove it?

Tags: php, html, serialization

I'm having a hard time formulating this question, and it's also very hard to google for, I find!

Symptoms: I have a string, "name_html" which is part of an array which gets serialized. When it arrives in the database I'm left simply with "name".

If I make the string "namehtml", it gets serialized as "nam".

I've tried this with various flavours of PHP, mySQL, and SQLite, but always get this result.

What obvious thing am I missing?? Thanks for any help with this! (And, yes, I have RTFM'ed the "serialize" docs on the PHP site. ;)

Comment: Please post the relevant code to give context to your question.

Comment: Does the field in your database have a limited length ? This would explain truncation. Also check if the field accepts binary data, serialize() sometimes uses null bytes.

Comment: When you can't seem to articulate your question or problem, simply create a short, generic testcase to demonstrate the issue. It will help everyone understand the problem.

Comment: What function/functions do you use to serialize the array?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP with MySQL, both have substring functions that can solve your problem if get it right.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`table`.`field`,'_',1)
FROM `infologicanet1`.`url_alias`;
```

Using MySQL's SUBSTRING_INDEX() function may solve your problem. In the avove example if the *table.field* value is *name_html* the SELECT will return *name*, but if you put -1 instead of 1, it will return *html*.

```
<?php
$string = 'name_html';
$needle = '_';
echo strstr($string, $needle, 1); //returns name
echo strstr($string, $needle, 0); //returns _html
echo stristr($string, $needle, 0);//returns _html
echo stristr($string, $needle, 1);//returns name
?>
```

Using PHP functions:

Comment: So... where does `serialize()` come into this?